# Help to read Atto di nascita

Tags: meaning, translation

I need help to read my grand-parent's 'atto di nascita'. See a piece of it in the attached image.

Following is what I can understand. Please help me with '...' (maybe the last part is his parents address)

Lucia Serra di anni trentotto .... domiciliata in Spezzano e de ... Giovanni Caliò di anni ... muratore
domiciliato in Spezzano ......... propria casa.

Thank you[image]

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I am a bit unsure this question is on-topic: on one hand, answering it without knowledge of the Italian language is basically impossible, on the other it is not really *about* Italian, more towards intepreting the handwriting. On the third hand, handwriting *can* be language-dependent so... I have provisionally answered it but I'd welcome input from the community

Comment: @DenisNardin My heart would love for this question to be on-topic. Should we not however consider the fact that the answer is not all generalizable (which is a property normally sought after on SE communities)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my best shot (what a peculiar handwriting!):

> [lo stesso è nato] Da Lucia Serra di anni trentotto, filatrice, domiciliata in Spezzano e da suo marito Giovanni Caliò di anni trentasei, muratore, domiciliato in Spezzano, nel dì ventisei detto mese ed anno alle ore due di notte nella propria casa.

Which translated roughly as

> [said person was born] from Lucia Serra, thirty-eight years old, spinner, resident in Spezzano and from her husband Giovanni Caliò, thirty-six years old, bricklayer, resident in Spezzano, on the twenty-sixth of the aforementioned month and year at two o'clock in the morning in their own house.

Comment: You must have some sort of superpower!